# My Mobile data switch is missing from my main Settings screen. How do I get it back?

Tags: settings, mobile-data

I used to have 4 toggle switches right on my main Settings screen: Airplane mode, WiFi, Bluetooth, and Mobile data. Now the Mobile data switch is gone, and I don't know where it went. It's been several months since I upgraded my Verizon LG Transpyre from Kit Kat to Lollipop, and I just noticed the difference yesterday. What happened to the menu item, and how do I go about getting it back?

Comment: Do you not have the switch in quick settings? Also, do you see that switch under Data usage? It is possible that they changed the appearance and entries in the Settings app, nothing big to think or worry about.

Comment: Yes, but I like it better where it was, on the main Settings screen with the other switches.